# Swift 3: Resizing UICollectionViewCell programmatically causes cells to overlap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift3

I am trying to create a `UICollectionView` with 3 cells below each other.
This is working properly. When I touch one cell, this cell should expand, the others should collapse to a specific height. Also working just fine.

The problem which I cannot solve; when I tap a cell, and it expands like I wanted it to; it overlaps the one below this one. The one below does not move down to make room for this cells new height.

How can I fix this?

This is what I have so far related to the `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell`

```swift
/**
 * Tempory 3 items
 */
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

/**
 * Defining the cells
 */
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! LicenseplateCollectionViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = .white
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 4

    if(indexPath.row > 0){
        cell.carStack.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
}


/**
 * Initial size
 */
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // The first cell always start expanded with an height of 300
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
    }else{
        // The others start with an height of 80
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: 80)
    }
}

/**
 * This functio shoud be handling everything like an accordeon system.
 * When I touch one cell, the others should collapse.
 */
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Animate resize of cell after tapping
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        // For now I have 3 cells, which I will loop
        for i in 0...2{
            // If this is the active cell (I just tapped on) ...
            if(indexPath.row == i){
                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! LicenseplateCollectionViewCell
                // This cell is expanded already, collapse it
                if(cell.frame.size.height > 200){
                    cell.carStack.isHidden = true
                    cell.frame.size = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: 80)
                }else{
                    // Open up this cell
                    cell.carStack.isHidden = false
                    cell.frame.size = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
                }
            }else{
                // Other cells besides the one I just tapped, will be collapsed
                print(indexPath.row, indexPath.section)
                let customPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
                print(customPath.row, customPath.section)
                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: customPath) as! LicenseplateCollectionViewCell
                cell.carStack.isHidden = true
                cell.frame.size = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: 80)
            }
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this.
The animation/resize should not happen in the `didSelectItemAt` override.

At first I have to define the array with cell configurations properly. Here I add a key 'active' with an boolean.

When I tap a cell, I switch the 'active' boolean to `true` within the objects array, and after that just call `collectionView.reloadData()`, this executes the `sizeForItemAt` override before the `UICollectionView` has been shown. This ensures the cell's are properly aligned and do exactly what they should do.

In the `sizeForItemAt` I return the proper height based on the 'active' boolean within the objects array.